# Java passing environment variable automatically escapes special characters

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, environment-variables

If I pass some variable as environment variable through run configurations in eclipse, then it automatically escapes the special characters. I want to pass some '\n' and '\r' characters for some formatting but these are automatically converted as '\\n' and '\\r' when i check it value in the code by debugging.

```
String value= System.getenv("envPassed");
System.out.println("envPassed= "+value);
```

So if envPassed is given as 'hi\n\rhello' in Run configurations, then it will be converted as 'hi\\n\\r' and output printed as

```
hi\n\rhello
```

whereas the output should come as

```
hi
hello
```

Do we have some way to make it work?

Comment: This seems to be a strange usage of the term “converted”. As far as I can see, nothing has been converted at all, you have inserted `hi\n\rhello` as variable definition and got a string containing `hi\n\rhello`.

Comment: seriously!!, it was even converting my double backslash to single here also. i have added one more backslash to show it as 2 slashes

Comment: The output should *not* be printed as two lines. It should be printed as `hi\n\rhello`. You provided backslashes, you got backslashes. You got back exactly what you provided. No conversion. The only thing in Java that translates those escape sequences to line termination characters is the Java compiler, when operating on string literals, and it isn't involved in this process. NB The carriage return should precede the linefeed.

Comment: You have it backwards. You are expecting that the `\n` and `\r` you entered literally into your run configuration becomes a true line break, in other words, you are expecting a conversion like it happens when you enter `\n\r` into a string literal. But the Eclipse dialog is not Java source code. Such a conversion does not happen. You get exactly what you entered, besides Eclipse’s `${name}` variable substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences like `\n` and `\r` are only converted to control characters when you enter them where such a behavior is documented, like for `String` literals in Java source code.

The Eclipse dialogs for environment variables or string substitution do not perform such a conversion, but transfer the string as entered. This is illustrated by the fact that your Java program reading and printing the value of the environment variable prints exactly what you have entered.

It’s a special property of the Java Debugger to show `String` content like the equivalent Java source code literal upon inspection. This is the only place, where a conversion happens.

It doesn’t seem to be the Eclipse developer’s intention to support multi-line strings for these variables. They seem to aim primarily at path strings and similar. However, I found a way, how you can insert a line break. Use `${system_property:line.separator}`, this will read the Java system property named `line.separator`, which is in the [list of always present system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--).

Comment: I don't think 'transfer the string as entered' is correct, at least for the case of setting a Linux environment variable. If you go to the environment window in your debug config, and set variable `A` with the 3-character value `{"B`, then this appears in the environment as 6 bytes, starting with `A=`. However, the double-quote is backslashed, so appears as 0x5c 0x22. Tested in the CDT, with C code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pre-treat the string before manipulating it... if you want to be safe you can use a little bit of regular expressions to ensure this will always work too:

```
String value = System.getenv("MyEnv");
if ( value != null ) {
    value.replaceAll("\\\\n(\\\\r)?", "\n" );
}
System.out.println( value );
```

Please note that the four backslashes are not a mistake - this is necessary because String.replaceAll() interprets the pattern string as both a string and a regular expression.

Hope this helps!